# ExpandableListView with childClickListener in Fragment and not in CustomAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I want to handler my expandableListView child element click in my fragment where i have the ExpandableListView.

Now, i handler it in getChildView adapter method..How can i handler this in Fragment?

I tried with this:

```
     implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener{
        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    ....}

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int  childPosition, long id) {
            Log.d("enter","enter");
            return false;
        }
```

But never enter in it..

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment you can get a reference to the ExpandableListView and then set the OnChildClickListener to the fragment itself.

```
mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);
```

The fragment must implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.

Comment: If you don't have any child in your list, only OnGroupClickListener will be called. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener.html).

Comment: I have childs, and set it with adapter, and later notify data change to adapter, i can see the childs but i cant dettect click event.

Comment: Are the children enabled on the adapter? By overriding [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#isChildSelectable).